# GNU Assembler - why doesn't -4(%rbp) override frame pointer on stack?

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Consider the following disassembly code:

```
_sum:
0000000100000f60    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000f61    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100000f64    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100000f67    movl    %esi, -0x8(%rbp)
```

As far as I know, `%rbp` is a 64 bit register so it means that `pushq %rpb` allocates 8 bytes on stack. If it does so, why is `movl %edi, -0x4(%rbp)` valid? I believe it overrides 4 bytes of already saved `%rbp` which has to be used to return from procedure later on. `%edi` and `%esi` are arguments passed to `sum` function.

Comment: It would be "valid" instruction even with +4 displacement (overwriting the old `rbp` value), the question is whether it makes sense. Partially overwriting the preserved value wouldn't make much sense, so your question has good logic, except you missed the memory layout, thinking this will land elsewhere. But questioning validity of instruction in asm is sort of weird, as long as it compiles, it is valid. If you would **want intentionally** to change only 32 bits of that value, then doing `movl %edi,4(%rbp)` is certainly one of possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack grows downward. What `pushq` does is:

```
RSP  ← RSP – 8;
Memory[SS:RSP]  ← SRC; (* push quadword *)
```

So the last value you pushed (i.e. the old value of `%rbp`) is at `(%rsp)`, and anything at negtive offsets from `%rsp` is "free space".

Comment: "free space" called "red zone", to be overwritten by next `push` or `call`, so one should be well aware of what he is doing, when using it (compilers do, I would recommend to stay away from it in manual asm from/for beginner, rather including `sub/add rsp`).

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I misunderstood the memory layout but now it makes perfect sense.